# The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, jstl

I picked up a newly created maven webapp project, and wants to do the simplest of the mvc application with it. my environment looks like so:

```
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>  
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-cglib-repack</artifactId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>

        <!-- particular arears-->
         <dependency>
           <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
           <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- -->

       <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
       <hibernate.version>3.6.1.Final</hibernate.version>
       <hibernate-cglig-repack.version>2.1_3</hibernate-cglig-repack.version>
       <log4j.version>1.2.14</log4j.version>
       <javax-servlet-api.version>2.5</javax-servlet-api.version>
       <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.10</hsqldb.version>
       <mysql-connector.version>5.1.6</mysql-connector.version>
       <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.5.2</slf4j-log4j12.version>
       <slf4j-api.version>1.5.8</slf4j-api.version>
       <javaassist.version>3.7.ga</javaassist.version>
       <taglibs.version>1.1.2</taglibs.version>


        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>admin-webapp</finalName>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>endorsed</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>sun.boot.class.path</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- javaee6 contains upgrades of APIs contained within the JDK itself.
                             As such these need to be placed on the bootclasspath, rather than classpath of the
                             compiler.
                             If you don't make use of these new updated API, you can delete the profile.
                             On non-SUN jdk, you will need to create a similar profile for your jdk, with the similar property as sun.boot.class.path in Sun's JDK.-->
                        <compilerArguments>
                            <bootclasspath>${settings.localRepository}/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/6.0/javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar${path.separator}${sun.boot.class.path}</bootclasspath>
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                            <version>6.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat60</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    <tomcat.home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</tomcat.home>
    <web.context>${project.artifactId}</web.context>
</properties>
```

my applicationContext is as simple as:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.personal.springtest.admin.webapp" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

web.xml as simple as so:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>iwadminservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/project-admin-webapp-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>iwadminservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my controller is just like so:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/")
   public String Home(){
    System.out.print("THIS IS a demo mvc, i think i like it");
    // this is temporary, will use viewresolver when everything clears up
    return "/views/home.jsp";
   }

}
```

my view is:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

the error I'm getting is

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

**Question 1**: i'm wondering if it's due to the versions I'm using, I think I've read something about supported version in tomcat, and the java ee version used.don't really get from that a way to fix my problem. How can I fix this?

**Question 2**: before this error I was having code 400 because I wasn't pointing it to `views/home.jsp` correctly but I did notice that when I run the app in netbeans, it opens the browser with the url: http://localhot:8080/ while i was expecting http://localhost:8080/admin-webapp/ admin-webapp being the name of my war. I believe this is a problem and would like to address it.

Comment: Tomcat indeed doesn't ship with JSTL at all. Read more at our JSTL wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstl

Comment: thanks for the answer , any idea about the question 2.it seems to border me a lot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the JSTL implementation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you manually include the JSTL jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks jeff it's fixed now.THe question is also very dear to me.the application is still starting from `http://localhost:8080/` instead of `http://localhost:8080/nameofmywar/` how can that be fixed ? thanks

Comment: It sounds like this isn't really a problem with your app, but rather you want to edit the run configuration in NetBeans.  In the NetBeans project properties, under the "Run" category, what's the "Context Path" setting?  It sounds like there's no context path, or it's set to the root (/).  If it's blank, then put in "admin-webapp".

Answer (score -1):

1. Download both the JSTL API and JSTL implementation from [here](https://jstl.java.net/download.html)
2. Add this directive: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`
3. Paste the JAR file in your WEB-INF/lib folder. This should work. (It
   worked for me.)